# import slidingmenu library in Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I use **Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2** and I want to import SlidingMenu library into this.
when I select **Import project** and select the library folder, eclipse doesn't find any project in that folder.

my library is right because I can import it to ADTBundle and my problem is with **Indigo Service Release 2** and I should use this release.

do you have any solution?

Comment: If you think it's a problem with Eclipse, you should probably contact them instead. You're not asking a programming question, you're asking for help with a software product then...

Comment: I think that maybe someone have or **another slidingMenu library** or **Previous version of Sliding Menu library** that compatible with this Eclipse or **another solution to import** this library

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: `Project Properties -> Andoid -> Add`... (bottom of the screen)

Please ensure that `SlidingMenuLibrary` have `Is Library` Option checked.